# "These are people" vs "These are the people"

Tags: grammar

Should I use "the" in the following sentence or not? Are they both grammatical? If yes, what difference does it create?

Here's the example:

> - These are **(the)** people who were present there when the accident happened.

To me it seems that If I don't use "the" it means there were other people who were present at the time of the accident besides them. They are not the only ones who were present there. I am not sure. Please explain.

I have found many examples on the internet where in contexts like this I have seen sometimes **the** is used sometimes not.

Answer (score 2):

You are right with your assumption:

> To me it seems that If I don't use "the" it means there were other
>   people who were present at the time of the accident besides them. They
>   are not the only ones who were present there.

The word 'the' is a definite article. In this case, using 'the' before the noun 'people' makes it (the noun) unique. It makes clear that those people (and only those people) have something in common: they were present when the accident happened.

Further reading: https://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/definite-article/